# Dimension attributes in SSAS browser window

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssrs-2008, ssas

I am facing an issue with SSAS. I created data cube from Data source view with the required measures and dimensions but I am unable view my dimension table attributes in Browser window after deploying the cube. I wanted to do this to implement drill down on time dimension for my SSAS report. I created Time hierarchy for the dimension and then created attribute relationships. I deployed the cube which went on successfully. But I am not able view dimension attributes under my dimensions in browser.

I believe this is related to some attribute setup issue. Can anyone please throw some light on this.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: Maybe make some pics of your Dimension and Dimension in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply. I guess problem is solved now. Actually I was also having issues when processing the cube. Hence, I deployed the cube by ignoring all errors before I processed the cube
 For future visitors: My workaround is: 
 Right Click in "Cube" => "Process" => "Change Settings" => "Dimension Key Errors"

Active "User Custom Error Configuration"

Set "Ignore Errors" for this four drop down list "Key Not Found" "Duplicated Key" "Null key converted to unknown" "Null key not allowed"

The problem with keys will be ignored. Mine was an academic project and for now, I did not see any serious implications after verifying data loaded with this settings. 
 I would welcome advice of other experts with some other solution for this problem.

Thank You.